# Resize ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I want to create an arraybuffer, I write: `var buff = new ArrayBuffer(size)`

But how is it possible to resize an existing buffer? I mean, adding some more bytes at the end of the buffer.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

```
var buff = new ArrayBuffer(32);
buff[31] = 43;
var newBuff = new ArrayBuffer(buff.byteLength*2);

for (var i=0;i<buff.byteLength;i++){
    newBuff[i] = buff[i];
}

buff = newBuff;
```

I've done it in C++ like this. Just made a bigger array and copy the contents over and then return the larger array and set it as the original.

Comment: In JS one should use TypedArray.prototype.set() for copying between arrays, as Jon Lennart Aasenden suggested.

Comment: I'm so perplexed as to the reason why this is accepted. **The content of an `ArrayBuffer` cannot be _directly_ accessed with `[]`, but only through _Views_ such as _Typed arrays_ and `DataView`s.** What the code's treating is PROPERTIES, not the CONTENT of those. You see the content: `console.log(new Uint8Array(buf));`.

Comment: set() is not always acceptable, it is slow when copying from shared to normal array buffer

Comment: This will never work. All the code above does is it creates new properties on the array buffer. It does not actually copy the contents. It is like doing this: `
var arr={};
arr[31] = 43;`

Answer (score 34):

No set on the ArrayBuffer itself. There is [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set) on the TypedArray though. Use like this:

```
var oldBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(20);

var newBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(40);
new Uint8Array(newBuffer).set(oldBuffer);
```

Comment: set() works but don't use like that because set doesn't return a value you'll have no pointer to the new array

Comment: the example given works just fine. the code doesn't need a poiinter to the `Uint8Array` because it is only using it to access the `set` function

Comment: or in other words if you don't need the view then it is okay to call like that, otherwise you should first assign the view to a variable

Comment: I don't know why but in my Firefox 65 provided example does not work. After `new Uint8Array(newBuffer).set(oldBuffer)` newBuffer contains zeroes. To fix that I had to provide typed array to set(): `new Uint8Array(newBuffer).set(new Uint8Array(oldBuffer))` — in this case it works as expected.

Comment: Make sure to pass an ArrayBuffer as argument for `set()`. If you pass another `Uint8Array` and it's bigger you get a `RangeError`.

Comment: Like Dmitry said, the example won't work unless `set()` is called with a `Uint8Array` as a parameter. [The spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-%typedarray%.prototype.set-typedarray-offset) only defines a behavior when an array or a typed array is passed as the first argument.

Answer (score 16):

The way to do that would be [`ArrayBuffer.transfer(oldBuffer, newByteLength)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/transfer), like so:

```
var buffA = new ArrayBuffer(30);
var buffB = ArrayBuffer.transfer(buffA, 40);

// buffA is now an empty array buffer (`buffA.byteLength === 0`)
// whereas buffB is a new buffer that starts with a's contents
// and ends with 10 bytes that are 0s.

// Much faster than manually copying. You could even just do:

var buffA = new ArrayBuffer(30);
buffA = ArrayBuffer.transfer(buffA, 40);

// Or as a prototype method

ArrayBuffer.prototype.resize = function(newByteLength) {
    return ArrayBuffer.transfer(this, newByteLength);
}

var buffA = new ArrayBuffer(30);
buffA = buffA.resize(40);
```

However (as of October 2017) there is 0% browser support (not even Node.js support) and is not even drafted yet.

---

Until this is available, you can use the polyfill given on the page, which copies 8 bytes at a time, so is relatively quick for large arrays (Though it does not empty the given array, which is impossible to do).

Here is a modified version using [`TypeArray.prototype.set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set) instead of for loops:

```
if (!ArrayBuffer.transfer) {
  ArrayBuffer.transfer = function(oldBuffer, newByteLength) {
    var srcBuffer = Object(oldBuffer);
    var destBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(newByteLength);
    if (!(srcBuffer instanceof ArrayBuffer) || !(destBuffer instanceof ArrayBuffer)) {
      throw new TypeError('Source and destination must be ArrayBuffer instances');
    }
    var copylen = Math.min(srcBuffer.byteLength, destBuffer.byteLength);

    /* Copy 8 bytes at a time */
    var length = Math.trunc(copylen / 64);
    (new Float64Array(destBuffer, 0, length))
      .set(new Float64Array(srcBuffer, 0, length));

    /* Copy the remaining 0 to 7 bytes, 1 byte at a time */
    var offset = length * 64;
    length = copylen - offset;
    (new Uint8Array(srcBuffer, offset, length))
      .set(new Uint8Array(destBuffer, offset, length));

    return destBuffer;
  };
}
```

[EDIT]

alternate version of the above that doesn't use ArrayBuffer namespace, and takes a slightly different approach

```js
          function arrayBufferTransfer(oldBuffer, newByteLength) {
             const 
             srcArray  = new Uint8Array(oldBuffer),
             destArray = new Uint8Array(newByteLength),
             copylen = Math.min(srcArray.buffer.byteLength, destArray.buffer.byteLength),
             floatArrayLength   = Math.trunc(copylen / 8),
             floatArraySource   = new Float64Array(srcArray.buffer,0,floatArrayLength),
             floarArrayDest     = new Float64Array(destArray.buffer,0,floatArrayLength);
             
             floarArrayDest.set(floatArraySource);
                 
             let bytesCopied = floatArrayLength * 8;
             
         
             // slowpoke copy up to 7 bytes.
             while (bytesCopied < copylen ) {
                 destArray[bytesCopied]=srcArray[bytesCopied];
                 bytesCopied++;
             }
             
           
             return destArray.buffer;
         }
```

Comment: Since this answer was written, the polyfill listed on the referenced page has been updated to a version without loops, so that is worth a quick look.

Comment: **Heads up!** It's a Very Bad Idea to do feature checks like `if(!ArrayBuffer.transfer) { ...}`. You should just override it without checking. Because if the `ArrayBuffer.transfer` method gets implemented, but ends up having different functionality (e.g. different params, or in different order, or whatever), then your code will suddenly break one day when browsers implement the real `ArrayBuffer.transfer`. If the standard had already been set in stone (and just not implemented in runtimes yet), then it would be fine.

Comment: The proposal was withdrawn so this answer is dead

Comment: @leumasme The `ArrayBuffer transfer` proposal now is in Stage 3: https://dev.to/hemanth/updates-from-the-94th-tc39-meeting-48mb

Comment: @Mörre hmm interesting, the original proposal repo https://github.com/domenic/proposal-arraybuffer-transfer was marked as withdrawn in Oct2021 and the linked mdn docs article deleted. The new proposal repo https://github.com/tc39/proposal-arraybuffer-transfer was created in Dec2022.

Comment: Looks like support for `transfer()` has been added in (most) major browser release versions as of Jan. 2024 (or so). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/transfer) / [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=arraybuffer.transfer)

Comment: Yup, it is part of the ecma standard by now. Still not added to Node/Deno though, hopefully for NodeJS 22 it is. Also `resize()` and a few other properties isn't `@types/node` yet but they are in the NodeJS.

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is the "set" method. After creating a new, larger array, simply call the set function and copy over the older content.

Comment: There is no `.set()` method on an `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: You have to make a Typed Array (view) over the `ArrayBuffer`, then call `set` on that.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

[From the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer) :

> The ArrayBuffer is a data type that is used to represent a generic,
>   **fixed-length** binary data buffer.

I don't know what you try to do but obviously you don't use them how they're meant to be used.

[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) is a good starting point to learn how to use typed arrays in JavaScript.

Comment: then how is it possible to create a new one, which begins with the old one's elements?

Comment: Are you looking for views ? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/ArrayBufferView If not there are some examples in the page I linked to in my answer.

Comment: @donkaka Because in both cases you're creating fixed-length buffers.

Comment: An `ArrayBuffer` does not always have a fixed length. It can be `resizable`.

Answer (score 1):

> ### Resizing `ArrayBuffers`
>
> `ArrayBuffer` objects can be made resizable by including the `maxByteLength` option when calling the `ArrayBuffer()` constructor. You can query whether an `ArrayBuffer` is resizable and what its maximum size is by accessing its `resizable` and `maxByteLength` properties, respectively. You can assign a new size to a resizable `ArrayBuffer` with a `resize()` call. New bytes are initialized to 0.
>
> These features make resizing `ArrayBuffer`s more efficient — otherwise, you have to make a copy of the buffer with a new size.

Some `ArrayBuffer`s are born resizable with a `maxByteLength` constructor argument. They're resizable with [`ArrayBuffer.prototype.resize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/resize).

Answer (score 0):

Most answers seem to me quite outdated. Here I explain why and show the new alternatives (which are more efficient.)

#### New Way To Do It

That approach won't release the memory allocated previously. That's why transfer exists (you may need to run with **Node20+**):

`ArrayBuffer.prototype.transfer()` usage isn't very well described in the second most upvoted answer either.

```js
const oldBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(20);
const ones = new Uint8Array(oldBuffer).fill(1);

const newSize = 40;
const newBuffer = oldBuffer.transfer(40);

// old buffer is detached, memory is freed (byteLength=0).
console.log(oldBuffer, newBuffer);
```

You can also transfer to a smaller ArrayBuffer.

A similar approach will be available with `resize` at some point.

#### Comments/Context

- Array buffers and Views (just a wrapper around it the buffer) were fixed length until 2023
- By 2023 most browsers and Node JS implemented methods [to transfer ArrayBuffers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/transfer) i.e similar to resizing.
- `ArrayBuffer.prototype.resize()` isn't currently supported everywhere. You can find what is and is not supported [in this MDN table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer).

An important note from transfer (link above):

> transfer() is very efficient because implementations may implement this method as a zero-copy move or a realloc — there does not need to be an actual copy of the data.

#### Comments on the other answers

TL;DR most written before 2023 are outdated.

The workaround was to *write a short arraybuffer into a larger arraybuffer*, since we could not resize them nor the views.

In your standard array notation that would be trivial with say `Array.concat` or  `Array.push` and so on. These methods aren't there in TypedArrays.

So you create a new array and set the new elements.

Here is a runnable example (you may have to run it in nodejs though.):

```js
const oldBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(20);
const newBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(40);

const ones = new Uint8Array(newBuffer);//fills w 0s

// write small array into larger one, start at offset 0
ones.set(new Uint8Array(oldBuffer).fill(1)); // 1s

console.log(oldBuffer, newBuffer);
```