# Best practice for self-resizing TypedArray?

Tags: javascript, typedarray

I'd like to use a `Float32Array` similarly to a C++ `std::vector<float>`, where I can push items to the end of the array and it automatically resizes itself when it runs out of space.

I noticed on MDN that `ArrayBuffer` has an [experimental `transfer` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) for this purpose, which seems like a good candidate. What other ways can I implement a self-resizing `TypedArray`?

Answer (score 1):

Googling for the exact same request, I found this answer:

TypedArrays are not Arrays but ArrayBuffers, and thus fixed length: you cannot use push() on them :-( . see more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

So apparently the only solution is brute-force ( see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600895/resize-arraybuffer) ). But if your intention was for some intensive operations (webGL, sound), you won't like that. In various tutos peoples are casting into Float32Array as they bind their buffer (e.g., `gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.vertexArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);` ), maybe it's not so bad... But I agree it does not sound optimal.

Comment: I think at this point I'm just waiting for something like the experimental `transfer` method to become standard.